# Deploy a standalone node.js server from WebStorm express project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webstorm

Total rookie question, however in my hours searching have not found a proper solution:

I have made a `Node.js`/`express` server using `WebStorm` IDE, tested it and run it successfully, however now that it is complete, I would like to be able to run it manually as a standalone project.

I have tried just running the `www` js file, which does start the server, however some functionality is lost, such as being unable to find and run a python script (not found).

My question is how do I fully transfer all the functionality incorporated in the WebStorm project so that server can be run outside of the IDE?

ADD: Currently only python scripts in the /bin directory will be found (server terminal run location)

Comment: WebStorm does nothing special for running Node apps... You should be able to cd in your Express app directory in terminal and type `node bin/www` to start your server